# Send blob image to php

Tags: javascript, php, server, blob

I've created a dynamic upload and I want to send each blob to server after the images are cropped.
The problem is that it's sent only the last append and I don't know why.

```
var g = 0;    
for(var j = 1;j <= boxno;j++) //boxno = 4 pics (I can have as much as I want)
{
    input = $("#input"+j);
    if(input.val().length !== 0)//check if input has any values
    {
        pcanvas = $("#pcanvas"+j)[0];
        context = pcanvas.getContext("2d");
        formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
        var blob = dataURLtoBlob(pcanvas.toDataURL('image/png'));
        formData.append("pcanvas_"+g+"[]", blob);
        g++;
    }
}

var info = {
    userid:userId,
    username:userName,
    picNr: g
}

formData.append("info[]", info["userid"]);
formData.append("info[]", info["username"]);
formData.append("info[]", info["picNr"]);

$.ajax({
    url: "/send.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: formData,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(data) {
        console.log("error");
    },
    complete: function(data) {}
});

function dataURLtoBlob(dataURL) {
    var BASE64_MARKER = ';base64,';
    if (dataURL.indexOf(BASE64_MARKER) == -1) {
        var parts = dataURL.split(',');
        var contentType = parts[0].split(':')[1];
        var raw = decodeURIComponent(parts[1]);
        return new Blob([raw], {
            type: contentType
        });
    }

    var parts = dataURL.split(BASE64_MARKER);
    var contentType = parts[0].split(':')[1];
    var raw = window.atob(parts[1]);
    var rawLength = raw.length;
    var uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(rawLength);

    for (var i = 0; i < rawLength; ++i) {
        uInt8Array[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    return new Blob([uInt8Array], {
        type: contentType
    });
}
```

Now if I send using this method is sent only "pcanvas3", the last loop. But If I put $.ajax inside the loop is working, but I don't want this, because I want to add into my db and is adding 4 times the same results (also I create new folder for a specific upload, so if I add inside the loop $.ajax it creates 4 folders)

Here is my php.

```
$id = $_POST['info'][0];
$username = $_POST['info'][1];
$picNr = $_POST['info'][2];
$shuffledid = str_shuffle($id);
$uniqueid = $id.$shuffledid;
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/_user/_tests/en/'.$uniqueid;
if(!file_exists($path))
{
    mkdir($path,0755);
}
for($g = 0; $g <= $picNr; $g++)
{
    $virtualbg = imagecreatetruecolor(400,410);
    $tmp_file = $_FILES['pcanvas_'.$g]['tmp_name'][0];
    $pic = imagecreatefrompng($tmp_file);
    list($width,$height,$type) = getimagesize($tmp_file);
    imagecopyresampled($virtualbg,$pic, 0,0,0,0, 400,410,$width,$height);
    imagejpeg($virtualbg,$path.'/pic_'.$g.'.jpg');
    imagedestroy($pic);
    imagedestroy($virtualbg);
}
```

As you can see I'm passing through each "pcanvas_0,1,2,3,4" but only the last one it gets the tmp_files.
What I'm doing it wrong? I think the problem is on my append. I've tried to append something else to the formData("pcanvas.. and it works but my blob is not appended.

Thank you!

Comment: You're currently overwriting all the variables on each iteration so they will only contain the data from the last iteration.

Comment: But I'm using pcanvas_$g which is creating pcanvas_1,2,3 etc.

Comment: You're still overwriting every single variable (except from `g`) in the loop. `formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);` replaces any previous content of `formData`. After the loop, it will only contain what you set it to in the last iteration. Just add `var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);` before the for-loop instead (and remove it from inside the loop).

Comment: omg thank you! After 3 days this was the problem. Tnx!